# Shuffling algorithm suitable?

Tags: java, algorithm, random

Just checking that this shuffling algorithm is suitable. Or maybe there could be improvements?

```
public static void shuffleArray(Object[] arr, Random rnd){
    int lastIndex = arr.length - 1;
    for (int i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++){
        int k = nextInt(i,lastIndex+1, rnd);
        Object a = arr[i];
        Object b = arr[k];
        arr[i] = b;
        arr[k] = a;
    }
}

//Returns an integer between start(inclusive) and end(exclusive) [start..end) 
public static int nextInt ( int start, int end, Random rnd);
```

Comment: Those +1 and -1 hurt my eyes.

Comment: Hmm, there is `Collections.shuffle()`, any reason why you don't use that?

Comment: I wish to shuffle an array of `byte`(s). And I believe it will be tedious todo type conversions, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1520212/59087

Answer (score 1):

One small thing is during the last iteration of the loop, the last element is swapped with itself.

Why not just use the `Collections.shuffle` as a guide?

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
    } else {
        Object arr[] = list.toArray();

        // Shuffle array
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(arr, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));

        // Dump array back into list
        ListIterator it = list.listIterator();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            it.next();
            it.set(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}

private static void swap(Object[] arr, int i, int j) {
    Object tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

This could be altered to:

```
public static void shuffleArray(Object[] arr, Random rnd) {
    for (int i=arr.length; i>1; i--) {
        int j = rnd.nextInt(i);
        Object tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, I spotted the last element self-swap too. However,`j` in your example is being restricted in a similar way to `k`.

Comment: @Kurent Ah, you're right about `j`, I didn't see that. Nice catch, I'll edit my answer.